hotlink protection by htaccess
How can I prevent my website content from being displayed outside of it.
my website :
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" disablepictureinpicture src="../videos/vid1.mp4" controls></video>
Other websites :
<video src="https://mywebsite.com/dir/videos/vid1.mp4" controls></video>
I couldn't with the code below :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [F]

I want the content to be displayed in every directory of my website :
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" disablepictureinpicture src="videos/vid1.mp4" controls></video>
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" disablepictureinpicture src="../videos/vid1.mp4" controls></video>
I appreciate any help.

"I couldn't with the code below" - What happens exactly? Where have you put that code (ie. Which .htaccess file and where in that .htaccess file? The order of these directives are important if you have other rules in the the config file.) "I want the content to be displayed in every directory of my website" - This would seem to be unrelated to "hotlinking protection"? Unless maybe you are suggesting the above code is also blocking access on your site? If so, what is your referrer-policy? Have you examined the HTTP request headers?

thank you very much for your response. Yes, I put this code in the .htaccess file, and when I checked, I found that it blocks access to both my site and other sites. no, I do not have a referral policy with  element (please guide me) @MrWhite

Have you checked if a Referer header gets send with the request for a video file, using your browser dev tools?

Is your site really only using HTTP, not HTTPS? "Have you examined the HTTP request headers?"

"I put this code in the .htaccess file" - But where in the .htaccess file (or is this literally the only rule you have?) and which .htaccess file?

My problem was solved with @MrWhite guidance, and i found the below links by searching (from MrWhite, thank you very much for your activity) :
Preventing hotlinking and .htaccessWeird Hotlinking protection via .HTACCESSHotlink protection, correct .htaccess rules?
For me both the below code worked :
code 1 :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [F]

code 2 :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [NC,F]

code 3 :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [F,NC,L]

1 - But i don't understand the difference between them (i know that https is involved) :
code 1 : .com/.*$
code 2 : \.com
2 - Which of these two codes is better ?
I don't know much about the rules of the .htaccess

^ anchors a regex pattern to the start of the test string, $ anchors it to the end.  ^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.com demands that the value starts with something matching the pattern, whereas ^https://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ demands that the whole test string matches the pattern from start to end - but since it allows for an arbitrary amount of arbitrary characters at the end after the final /, that will work as well here.
